# OSGi : Are bundles/jars cached?

Tags: osgi

I was always wondering: When I install a jar in OSGi, for example with "install file:///xyz" or with "install http://xyz.org/my.jar" - does OSGi only store a reference? Or does it copy the file to some sort of local repository?

I am especially interested what happens for remote resources (like "install http://...").

cheers,
T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are cached. From http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-bundle-cache.html:

> The OSGi specification states that the framework must cache bundles
>   and their run-time state, but it does not explicitly define how this
>   should be done. As a result, each OSGi framework implementation is
>   likely to cache bundles differently.